# Is the "subring relation" transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R_0, R_1, R_2$ be rings (not necessarily unital, not necessarily commutative). Interpret "$\subseteq_r$" as "is a subring of". Is the following a theorem?

$$R_0\subseteq_r R_1 \text{ and } R_1\subseteq_r  R_2$$
$$\implies$$
$$R_0\subseteq_r R_2$$

Comment: What are your own thoughts on it? What is known and what needs to be shown?

Comment: What need to show that $R_0$, as a subset of $R_2$, is closed under the subtraction and multiplication of $R_2$. We know this is true for $R_0$ with respect to $R_1$, and for $R_1$ with respect to $R_2$.

Comment: There's more to being a subring. It also means that the multiplication and addition of $R_1$ are the same as those of $R_2$. Ditto for $R_0$ and $R_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially thought that "$\subseteq_r$" as "is an ideal of" and so I wrote a post that I deleted xD. Anyways, I realized that your question is kind of trivial.

Indeed, if $R_0\subseteq_r R_1$ and $R_1\subseteq_r R_2$, then clearly $R_0\subseteq R_2$ (as sets), now since we're working with non-unitary rings, we only have to prove that if $+$ and $\cdot$ are the binary operations of $R_2$, then $(R_0, +, \cdot)$ is ring. But this follows easily from the fact that $(R_0,+,\cdot)$ is a subring of $(R_1,+,\cdot)$ (here we're using that $R_1$ is a subring of $R_2$), i.e., $R_0$ is a ring, which is also subset of $R_2$, so $R_0$ is a subring of $R_2$.

Comment: Thank goodness, I thought I was going crazy! :P +1. (Note to the OP: the statement is true for unitary rings as well; Xammm's point "since we're working with non-unitary rings" refers to the fact that the subring condition has one fewer clause in the non-unitary case.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber in unitary rings we'd have $1_{R_0}=1_{R_1}$ and $1_{R_1}=1_{R_2}$, then $1_{R_0}=1_{R_2}$, right?

Comment: Exactly. I just wanted to clarify for the OP that you weren't saying that the result *failed* in the unitary case - it just takes one more sentence.

Answer (score 0):

we have $(R_0,+)$ subgroup in $(R_1,+)$ and $(R_1,+)$ subgroup in $(R_2,+)$ then $(R_0,+)$ subgroup in $(R_2,+)$. 
$\forall x,y\in R_0$ then $xy\in R_0 \subseteq R_1 \subseteq R_2$ then $xy\in R_2$